# launch app on pressing power key and volume key at the same time

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

As per the title I want to open my app on pressing power key and volume key at the same time 
or pressing any key of device for 3-2 seconds.

Please suggest , I want to do something like few devices suggest "You can capture screenshots by pressing the Home key and the Power/Lock key simultaneously."

I tried below code , but it is not working :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    if ((intent.getAction().equals("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION")) && (( intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) || ( intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)))) {

    Intent  i  = new Intent(context , com.ht.longpresslaunch.MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(i);
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you come up with a solution on this question ? Thanks

Comment: no we dropped the idea ..

Comment: my guess is you really cant override this function since android system uses it as an alternative way of formatting and rebooting device.